# Zend 1.12: Issue with routing request to my controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am very new to Zend framework, and have lately struggled to route a request to my controller, which is not the IndexController created along with the sample project. 
Indeed I created a SpotController (with the index, add, delete, update methods and view files), and I cannot seem to access the index method as I get a **500 Internal Server Error**

Here is how I link to my controller in my IndexController's view for index method:

```
<p>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'spot','action'=>'index'),'default'); ?>">See spot</a>
</p>
```

Here is my **routes.ini** file (in APPLICATION_PATH/config) :

```
routes.routename.route = "spot"
routes.routename.defaults.module = default
routes.routename.defaults.controller = spot
routes.routename.defaults.action = index
```

And here is my **Boostrap.php** _initRouter() method :

```
protected function _initRouter(){
        $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/routes.ini');
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $router = $front->getRouter();
        $router->addConfig($config,'routes');
        $front->setRouter($router);
        return $router;
    }
```

I guess there is something that I am doing wrong, and I find the zend's documentation very inaccurate on this topic.
Just to let you know, I can access my IndexController just fine.

Thanks in advance, 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i would recommend you to turn php error display on, as you are on development stage by putting the following in your `application.ini` File

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

500 error type is internal server error and if you are using Apache server. You need to check your .htaccess files, these can come from different angels like `mod_rewrite module` not enabled in Apache, or required `RewriteBase` / rule in .htaccess (on shared hostings)
missing `AllowOverride All` in virtual host configurations

Your  `public/.htaccess` File should look like the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

hope that may help

Answer (score 0):

I deleted two rules in my .htaccess to make it look exactly how you recommended, and everything works fine :) Thanks a lot for your help !

Here are the two lines I removed if it may help anyone :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
```

Comment: Glad to hear that i could help you!. Happy new year